# Is it possible to connect XSSFPivotTable to external DataSheet (located at external workbook) via Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried the code below, but it is not working:

```
public static void addExternalPivot (String pathSource, String pathOutput, String NameOfTableSource) throws IOException{
    
    //source wb
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathSource);
    XSSFWorkbook wbSrc = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    //output wb
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathOutput);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new MyXSSFWorkbook();

    //create sheet for pivot
    XSSFSheet sheetOut = wb.createSheet("pivot");

    //get pivot from source
    XSSFPivotTable pSrc = wbSrc.getPivotTables().get(0);

    //parameters to  create pivot
    AreaReference source = wbSrc.getTable(NameOfTableSource).getArea();
    CellReference position = new CellReference("A5");
    Sheet dataSheet = pSrc.getDataSheet();

    //create pivot
    XSSFPivotTable pivotResult = sheetOut.createPivotTable(source, position, dataSheet);

    //save and close
    fis.close();
    wbSrc.close();

    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    wb.close();
    
}
```

I can copy datasheet directly to the output wb and create pivot, but it is not working for my case. Where i have to update 250 pivots in different files.

Comment: Hi user13896388, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please explain what exactly is not working? Is there an error message? Or just no result at all?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPivotCacheDefinition.createCacheFields(XSSFPivotCacheDefinition.java:182)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createPivotTable(XSSFSheet.java:4481)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createPivotTable(XSSFSheet.java:4450)
 at ru.excelTest.MyWorkbook.main(MyWorkbook.java:63)

Comment: Mistake in the row XSSFPivotTable pivotResult = sheetOut.createPivotTable(source, position, dataSheet);

Comment: I suppose that pivot cannot be created from external source (out of current wb). Program is trying to find dataSheet in the current wb, but can't do it because it is located in another wb (external).

Comment: I made working scenario when i tried to copy datasheet directly to the current wb, but it is not what i whant to do because of significant time and memory usage.